# opencv knearest neighbor

Tags: c++, opencv, nearest-neighbor, knn

I am using CVKnearest Class in opencv to classify 6 classes with 10 features as follows:

```
 CvKNearest knn(trainData, trainClasses, Mat(), false, K );
```

then I use :

```
 response = knn.find_nearest(testData,K,Results,nearests,dists);
```

but the Results is always 1 ,even if I give features of a training sample which should give me a distance of zero and be choosed as the class!

when I print the Mat Results as this:

```
FileStorage f;
f.open("result.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
f << "t" << Results;
f.release();
```

It gives me a floating number,

so my question is what am I doing wrong? or how should I get the right class labels?!

Comment: Did you ever find out what's wrong? I seem to have the same problem...

Comment: @diip_thomas yep ,I was sending the inputs in a wrong format